# Can I make Android Studio generate Dart constructors code with named parameters and add key?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

When I auto generate dart constructors, I would like the generator to make my constructors using named parameters and add key.

(Curly braces wrapping the constructor arguments)

Is there some easy trick I can perform to make Android Studio do this for me?

```
// Auto generated constructor without named parameters. 
// This is how Android studio currently generates my Widget constructors.
class MyTestModel {
  MyTestModel(this.a, this.b, this.c);

  final String a;
  final String b;
  final String c;
}

// Constructor with named parameters and key.
// This is how I would like Android Studio Auto Generate to behave.
class MyTestModelB {
  MyTestModelB({Key key, this.a, this.b, this.c}) : super(key: key);

  final String a;
  final String b;
  final String c;
}
```

So another way to phrase my question:

When I press "Command + N" and I use Android Studio to automatically generate my Dart constructor.

Currently Android Studio does not generate Named Parameter Constructors for me, neither does it add a key to the constructors.

Somewhere I guess there is a Template of some kind that Android Studio uses to autogenerate those constructors.
I guess I need to access that Template and modify it to have it autogenerate Named Parameter Constructors for me, and add key.
But where is it?

My installation of Flutter/Dart/Android studio is rather new.
From April/May 2020.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I don't know what has happened to my Android Studio, but now I can generate the constructors like a want them. Something must have happened! Maybe something got installed or updated? I don't know. If you know where exactly the settings for auto generate of Flutter constructors happens in Android Studio, I am interested to know. This is how my constructors look now:

```
class Avatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String photoUrl;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  const Avatar({Key key, this.photoUrl, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);
}
```

Comment: Did you find out how you changed this? I too also just get the default behavior (without named parameters) when generating the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The default constructor generator from Cmd+N (MacOS) will not generate named parameters constructor. You need to highlight one of your final variable (must be final), wait for the popup (see [video clip](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2021#issuecomment-377006878)) and select `generate constructor from final field` or press alt+shift+enter.

Comment: Android Studio 4.1 on Mac uses (Ctrl) ^N

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the 'named argument constructor' option in the generate menu, then you should install [Dart Data Class](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12429-dart-data-class) Plugin.